# Проблема с русским при запросах к базе данных вместо букв вопросы (Кодировка Utf-8)

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, кодировка, utf-8, mysql

База создана utf8 сравнение тож utf8

Запросы работают но 1 косяк вместо русского вопросы!Хэлп

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте, если еще не сделаны, внести все (!) изменения в код:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"); // Где-нибудь в начале PHP скрипта
$db->query( "SET CHARSET utf8" ); Установите кодировку общения с БД

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> // Добавьте в HEAD шаблона страницы
```

Comment: Лучший ответ MDJHD помогло,спасибо)вопрос закрыт

Comment: @dracon57, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом). Ну или удалите вопрос, что бы не висел не в отвеченных)

Answer (score 2):

Возможно вам надо установить кодировку (после коннекта к базе) с помощью [mysql set charset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php)

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);
```

[Здесь](https://wiki.linux.by/index.php/FAQ_PHP_MySQL_charset) подробно написано про кодировку БД MySql.

Comment: Cпасибо)иду пробывать.

Comment: Проблема осталась результат выдается но с ("????")

Comment: Проверяйте кодировку скрипта, который общается с базой. Она должна быть utf-8. Если нет, то кодируйте предварительно текст с помощью **iconv**

Comment: @dracon57 попробуй еще установить кодировку страницы header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");

Comment: уже и не знаю..везде utf 8 и так и прописана и в phpmyadmin она же...

Comment: @dracon57 покажи настройки БД -- выполни в phpmyadmin 'show create database db_name;'

Answer (score 0):

Скачайте программу Notepad++ и в разделе "кодировки" выберите utf8 без БОМ (не забудьте открыть файл в котором обработчик)

Comment: на centose делаю

Comment: А там есть изменение кодировки? В самой программе