# Не отображается шрифт в MySQL

Tags: phpmyadmin, шрифты, mysql

В `phpmyadmin` не отображается шрифт принятой информации в таблице, хотя в настройках выставлено `utf8_general_ci`. Может выставить `cp1251_general_ci`?

Comment: шрифт или все-таки кодировка??

Comment: кодировка! Прошу прощения! Так как быть?

Comment: а в какой кодировке вы ее передаете? И что значит не отображается? Вопросительные знаки вместо букв?

Comment: @Arty21, пожалуйста, продолжайте в [своем старом вопросе](/questions/296320/)

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

странный способ у вас на сайте для задания кодировки страницы, однако:)

Comment: Так то вот: <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">. отображается вот так Â íîÿáðå ïðîøëîãî ãîäà.

Comment: читайте мой ответ ниже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите мой ответ на похожий вопрос [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/295847#295870) вдруг поможет

Comment: Все получилось! Спасибо!