# Ошибка в кодировке

Tags: кодировка, php, mysql

при наборе следующего

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","alex","12345");
mysql_select_db("firstbd",$db);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM firma",$db);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $myrow["name"];
?>
```

выходит
�������
видимо что-то с кодировкой, файл `.htaccess` есть в папке,все равно кодировка не работает

Answer (score 1):

Гляньте один из моих ответов на подобный вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/295870/178576

Для вашего кода вместо:

```
$db->query( "SET CHARSET utf8" );
```

Используйте:

```
mysql_query( "SET CHARSET utf8" );
```

Если у вас не utf8, то замените на свою кодировку

Comment: все равно результат тот же

Comment: Вот когда я написал это под кодом в середине все нормально теперь,спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Нужно изначально задать кодировку соединения для получения данных:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES cp1251")
```

Comment: А куда ее прописать,я просто не очень разбираюсь

Comment: Сразу после mysql_select_db("firstbd",$db);

Comment: перед строкой в которой делаете выборку.