# Почему сбрасывается кодировка?

Tags: кодировка

Доброго времени суток!
Я осваиваю html и css, и всё мне понятно, но столкнулся с такой ситуацией. Редактировал чужой сайт, он был сделан криво, и на некоторых страницах в коде все русские буквы были превращены в непонятное безобразие, как это обычно бывает, если указана неправильная кодировка. Я установил её правильно, но она сбрасывалась при закрытии страницы, и после открытия кода, там снова вместо букв были одни каракули. Не на странице в интернете, а именно в самом коде, внутри страницы. В чём может быть причина, и как её исправить?

Ещё момент, связанный с каракулями. На странице устанавливал кодировку, но после сохранения она сбрасывалась. Почему она сбрасывается и не сохраняется при закрытии страницы? После сброса, естественно, все русские буквы превращались в каракули и чёрные ромбы.

`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` везде прописано, и именно эта кодировка сбрасывалась. А также, сбрасывалась на хостинге, когда я устанавливал её в выдвигающемся меню, которое становится доступно при редактировании кода.

То есть, все простейшие варианты, которые очевидны при такой проблеме, я перепробовал. Не помогло. Пробовал даже сделать новую страницу, заново, вручную, писал, вносил информацию, удалял прежнюю страницу, но и на новой странице снова всё портилось.

Буду рад увидеть ответ.
С уважением, Олег.

Comment: дали бы адрес страницы, можно было бы гипотезы проверить.

Comment: http://crbkimry.ru
На этом сайте, несколько страниц. На Главной много текста, в Документах тоже, я только что эти страницы открывал, чтобы проверить код - каракули. Если их открыть, ничего не делать, просто сохранить и выйти, то со страницы в интернете пропадёт весь русский текст и стили к нему, потому что в коде каракули.

Comment: …Либо перевести текст в другую кодировку. Вообще лучше на сайте использовать какую-то одну кодировку, что-бы не умножать путаницу.

Comment: у меня сайт отображается нормально. Но вебсервер, где находиться сайт, выдает в хедерах кодировку `Content-Type: text/html; charset=cp1251`. А некоторым браузерам срывает крышу, если в хедерах и в meta прописаны разные кодировки.

Comment: Это и сделал, браузер не трогал. Редактировал сам html-файл, и не один раз. Указал в вопросе ту строчку, где изменял кодировку с utf-8 на windows-1251 и обратно. У меня есть доступ к папке с этими страницами на хостинге.

Comment: В каких местах кодировки прописываются? Я, кроме html-файла не знаю, где ещё можно.

Comment: Кодировка прописывается в саомо html-документе тегом
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
в блоке head. И в http-ответе сервера. На сколько я помню распространённые сервера просто всегда указывают кодировку забитую у него в настройках (глобальных или для некоторой директории), и кодировка из ответа http-сервера перекрывается кодировкой указанной в html документе.

P.S. у вас кстати кривые ссылки в разделе «документы». В ссылках на файлы разделитель «\», вместо «/». \ в качестве разделителя это чисто виндовая приблуда, тяжёлое наследие тёмного прошлого.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может мой ответ поможет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/295847#295870 , если сайт на php, конечно. Если нет, то надо менять кодировку в настройках сервера на аналогичную с сайтом (ну или, как вариант (не лучший ИМХО), перекодировать страницы сайта в текущую кодировку). Как спросите у хостинг-провайдера, так как зависит от типа, настроек самого сервера.

Comment: Не заметил ссылку на сайт в комментарии. Посмотрел,  там у вас на различных страницах разные кодировки, что уже не есть хорошо, так что перекодируйте все в одну (лучше UTF8).

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы! Информацию проверю. Сайт делал не я, меня попросили посмотреть и исправить. Там действительно много ошибок.

Answer (score 2):

> Я установил её правильно

Как это было сделано? Если через меню браузера выбрана нужная кодировка то это и не должно было повлиять на сайт, это та кодировка которю использует браузер для просмотра страницы, она не сохраняется при закрытии вкладки например. И разумеется она не может повлиять ни на что за пределами вашего браузера.

Что-бы исправить сайт нужно на сервере либо отредактировать html-файл, или шаблон из которого генерируются HTML-страницы отдаваемые посетителям, указав правильную кодировку в специальном теге заголовка (блок <head>).

*Обновление*

Кодировка прописывается в саомо html-документе тегом

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

В блоке head. И в http-ответе сервера. На сколько я помню распространённые сервера просто всегда указывают кодировку забитую у него в настройках (глобальных или для некоторой директории), и кодировка из ответа http-сервера перекрывается кодировкой указанной в html документе.

P.S. у вас кстати кривые ссылки в разделе «документы». В ссылках на файлы разделитель «\», вместо «/». \ в качестве разделителя это чисто виндовая приблуда, тяжёлое наследие тёмного прошлого.